# Manage Bluetooth in Windows 8.1 stuck at searching

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

My Bluetooth controller is enabled in BIOS. I am trying to add a bluetooth device in Windows 8.1. When I go to PC and devices -> Bluetooth, the screen is stuck at searching for a bluetooth device. Also the On/Off switch [like here](https://superuser.com/questions/612742/how-to-turn-on-off-bluetooth-on-windows-8-1) is not showing. I get this:

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you make sure `Bluetooth Support Service` is running in Task Manager? If not, start the service from `Services.msc`. Also could you check Bluetooth switch is available in `Wireless` option under _PC Settings_ ? [See Bluetooth switch](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tblkc.png)

Comment: What is the make of the Bluetooth and network adapter? Check if a newer driver is available on the manufacturer's website. If the driver installation doesn't solve the problem, you might need to reinstall the driver after using [this registry hack](http://www.wiknix.com/solved-bluetooth-device-not-working-in-windows-8-1/), but try to undo it if everything works.

Comment: @ISAAC The service is running. There's no wireless option under PC settings. I think it's in Windows 8 but not 8.1. Bluetooth has its own entry under devices in 8.1

Comment: @harrymc It's Kinivo BTD-400. I used the drivers from the cd and the updated ones from broadcom.com. Same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled the device's driver software (even though it's the latest) and rebooted. Windows automatically installed the device and installed the driver with my intervention and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft's official [community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/bluetooth-problems-windows-81/d92f3429-7ff1-475e-aa6c-518274114f14) ,it would be resolved by any one of the following :

a)Device status might be not valid &

b)update the driver with manufacturer

Steps to check device status and updating device drivers were :

```
Method 1:

a)      Press Windows key + X, select Device manager.
b)      Expand the “Bluetooth” section to locate the Bluetooth adapter.
c)       Check if there is a yellow exclamation mark or a red cross mark over it.
d)      Right click on device and select properties.
e)      In the General tab, check the device status.

Method 2:

a)      Press Windows key + X, select Device manager.
b)      Expand the “Bluetooth” section and locate the Bluetooth adapter.
c)       Right click the device and select “Properties”.
d)      Click on the driver tab to check the current driver installed for that device.
e)      Click on the uninstall button to uninstall that driver.
f)       Now, install the new driver that you downloaded from the manufacturer’s website and check.
```

Apart from that if you are facing this issue after **windows update** :

Check whether the manufacturer's device driver was marked for use,since by default microsoft would override the device driver of manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Open run and type fsquirt.exe.
This will open a new window allowing you to send and recieve files the traditional Windows 7 way.

To resolve your issue, Open Task manager.
Under 'Processes' tab, check if Bluetooth Device Monitor(32 Bit) and Bluetooth OBEX Service(32 Bit) are running.
Then open the 'Startup' tab  and check if Btmshellex is enabled. If disabled, enable it.

Alternatively, you can try installing the [LATEST BLUETOOTH DRIVERS HERE](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23999&lang=eng&ProdId=3502). Select the driver based on your systems architecture.