# How can I toggle Bluetooth on and off via a shortcut or script in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth

Before upgrading to Windows 8.1 I used the bluetooth icon in the notifications area to turn bluetooth on and off. Now, in Windows 8.1 it requires about 6 clicks to get this job done through the new metro UI. See [How to turn on/off Bluetooth on Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/612742/how-to-turn-on-off-bluetooth-on-windows-8-1) for the slow way to get this job done.

I would like to go back to being able to toggle my bluetooth in a couple of clicks without having to leave my desktop. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, it can be done. I'm not sure if this is the easiest way, but it works

## Creating a batch file

1. Create a new `.bat` file and call it something like `bluetooth.bat`
2. Inside the file, paste the following script

> The script checks if the **Bluetooth Support Service** (**bthserv**) is running.
>
> If running, it stops the service. If stopped, it starts the service.

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "bthserv" ^| findstr "STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   net start "bthserv"
  ) else if /I "%%H" NEQ "STOPPED" (
   net stop "bthserv"
  )
)
```

3. Save the .bat and then run it as an **Administrator**

### Execution

If the service is **stopped**, you'll see:

> [image]

If the service is **running**, you'll see:

> [image]

If you want to stop the window from automatically closing, add a new line with `@pause` to the bottom of your script. Then you'll be prompted with `Press any key to continue . . .`.

**Edit from comments:**

The first time you use the batch file, add `@pause` to the bottom of the script and select `y` for any prompts that appear. Then test it out once more to make sure it's working as intended. If it is, you can remove `@pause`.

## Always run as Administrator

If you want, which I assume you will, for the `.bat` to **always run as Admin**, do the following:

1. Right click on your `bluetooth.bat` and click "Send to" -> "Desktop (Create Shortcut)

[image]

2. Right click on the *shortcut*, click properties, then find the "Shortcut" tab at the top. Click "Advanced"

[image]

3. Select "Run as Administrator"

[image]

4. From now on, run the shortcut instead! All done.

Comment: This does not work on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Ahmed What about it doesn't work? AFAIK the service name is the same. What error do you get, in specific?

Comment: No error, just after i ran the .bat file as administrator, my bluetooth is still on and my bluetooth speaker is still connected to computer.

Comment: Add @pause at the end of the script to see the error, to prevent the .BAT from automatically closing. Paste the output.

Comment: The following services are dependent on the Bluetooth Support Service service.
Stopping the Bluetooth Support Service service will also stop these services.

   Bluetooth Handsfree Service

Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N) [N]: y
The Bluetooth Handsfree Service service is stopping.
The Bluetooth Handsfree Service service was stopped successfully.

The Bluetooth Support Service service is stopping.
The Bluetooth Support Service service was stopped successfully.

Comment: I ran it again and it gave the appropriate turning "off" and turning "on" if run again.

Comment: Ah so it works now? Seems like you had to select yes for that initial. If it works as intended now I'll edit my answer with what you found.

Comment: Well, it's not doing anything. My bluetooth is still connected and playing music. Nothing seems to be affected.

Comment: @Ahmed Has something to do with the Bluetooth Handsfree Service. Go to services, find the Bluetooth Handsfree Service and grab the actual service name and I'll amend the code to stop and start both services at once. I think that'll fix it.

Comment: "BthHFSrv" and "bthserv"