# How can I toggle Bluetooth on and off via a shortcut on Windows 10 1903

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, autohotkey, windows-10-v1903

I would like to emulated with a shortcut the process of 1) opening the Action Center and 2) clicking on the bluetooth icon.

My solution was to use AHK to map a keyboard shortcut to running a .bat, which contains the script suggested in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/850650/how-can-i-toggle-bluetooth-on-and-off-via-a-shortcut-or-script-in-windows-8-1).

But the suggested service doesn't activate/remove the magic little blue icon of the bluetooth in the tray bar.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcCIW.png)

I have look for all bluetooth services that are turned on when I click on the bluetooth icon in action center and I have activated them via the suggested `.bat`, but still it's not working.

```
BluetoothUserService_182d916
bthserv
BthHFSrv  
BthHFEnum  
BthEnum   
BthHFAud
BthEnum
BthA2dp
Microsoft_Bluetooth_AvrcpTransport
```

Here are all the services:
[image]
[image]

My script (where I have replace Microsoft_Bluetooth_AvrcpTransport by all the service mentionned above):

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Microsoft_Bluetooth_AvrcpTransport" ^| findstr "STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   net start "Microsoft_Bluetooth_AvrcpTransport"
  ) else if /I "%%H" NEQ "STOPPED" (
   net stop "Microsoft_Bluetooth_AvrcpTransport"
  )
)

@pause
```

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1168551/turn-on-off-bluetooth-radio-adapter-from-cmd-powershell-in-windows-10

Comment: Thanks for this, I have asked another question, because I have trouble adapting the code for using it with a shortcut: https://superuser.com/questions/1494499

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create an [.ahk](https://www.autohotkey.com/) shortcut that starts a powershell:

```
#b::
Run, C:\Users\user\Desktop\bluetooth.ps1,,Hide 
return
```

Then you create a powershell:

```
If ((Get-Service bthserv).Status -eq 'Stopped') { Start-Service bthserv }
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::RequestAccessAsync()) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
$radios = Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::GetRadiosAsync()) ([System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]])
$bluetooth = $radios | ? { $_.Kind -eq 'Bluetooth' }
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioState,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
if ($bluetooth.state -eq 'On') {$BluetoothStatus = 'Off'} else {$BluetoothStatus = 'On'}
Await ($bluetooth.SetStateAsync($BluetoothStatus)) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
```

All credit goes to [@Ben N](https://superuser.com/a/1293303) and [@Scott Heath](https://superuser.com/a/1495417)

---

This script works when I launch it from VScode, when I copy-paste it in a powershell, or when I use a cmd to start it. But not when I double-click it or when I start it in `.ahk`. The work around was to create a `.bat` file with this

```
Run, C:\Users\user\Desktop\bluetooth.ps1,,Hide
```

And then call this `.bat` in ahk.

Comment: If the quoted powershell script doesn't work, as it didn't in my case, remove ` | Out-Null` from the final line and re-run, if it prints `DeniedByUser` then search for "Radio Privacy Settings" in start menu and allow apps to control radios.

Comment: For me the command in the bat looked like this:
`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File bluetooth.ps1`

Answer (score 2):

AutoHotkey v2.0 introduces a new syntax that replaces statements with functions, so the accepted answer is no longer a copy-and-paste solution.

To pull this off with AutoHotkey v2.0 on Windows 10.0.19045, I needed to create:

1. **toggle-bluetooth.ahk**

```
#b::
{
    Run( 'C:\Users\<user>\Documents\AutoHotkey\toggle-bluetooth.bat', , 'Hide' )
    return
}
```

(The signature `#b::` assigns hotkey Win+B to this function. See the [AHK docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm) for details on notation.)

2. **toggle-bluetooth.bat**

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File toggle-bluetooth.ps1
```

3. **toggle-bluetooth.ps1**

```
If ((Get-Service bthserv).Status -eq 'Stopped') { Start-Service bthserv }
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::RequestAccessAsync()) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
$radios = Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::GetRadiosAsync()) ([System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]])
$bluetooth = $radios | ? { $_.Kind -eq 'Bluetooth' }
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioState,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
if ($bluetooth.state -eq 'On') {$BluetoothStatus = 'Off'} else {$BluetoothStatus = 'On'}
Await ($bluetooth.SetStateAsync($BluetoothStatus)) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
```

---

It's very possible that using the `.bat` as a middleman is not necessary with some other approach. But this is the only thing that I could get to work.

Obvious thanks to @MagTun and @rokdd for developing this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stop/start these services for getting rid of the Bluetooth
traybar icon.

The display of the icon is controlled in the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Bluetooth`, by the DWORD value
`Notification Area Icon` whose value is `0` for Off and `1` for On.
This requires restarting Explorer to take effect.

The following two `.bat` files will do the job.

**Disable the Bluetooth notification area icon**

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Bluetooth" /V "Notification Area Icon" /T REG_DWORD /D 00000000 /F
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

**Enable the Bluetooth notification area icon**

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Bluetooth" /V "Notification Area Icon" /T REG_DWORD /D 00000001 /F
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Comment: Sorry I was clear enough, I do not want to get rid of the blue bluetooth icon, I want to start /stop the bluetooth, and when the bluetooth is on I want the blue icon, and when the bluetooth is stopped (and only then) I do not want the blue icon.

Comment: What was wrong with the [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1168551/turn-on-off-bluetooth-radio-adapter-from-cmd-powershell-in-windows-10) in a comment above?

Comment: The answer in the post works but I have some difficulties to adapt it so I can use it with a shortcut : https://superuser.com/questions/1494499

Comment: If that script works, the AutoHotKey command can be improved as `Run, powershell C:\path\to\bluetooth.ps1 On` and another shortcut for Off.

Comment: Yes, I could do that (which I am already doing) but I would like to use just one shortcut.

Comment: Easy enough to add a toggle to the AutoHotKey script so it does On/Off. Do you need help with that?

Comment: Thanks for your patience @harrymc!  Yes, your help is welcome because I could find a way to make my AutoHotKey script check the status of the bluetooth (so that it  "knows" if it needs to send `Run, powershell C:\path\to\bluetooth.ps1 On` or `Run, powershell C:\path\to\bluetooth.ps1 Off`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @harrymc, I ended up using a solution in powershell.