# Modify a powershell that receive argument On/off to start/stop service to a script that checks if service is on (or off) and stops it (or starts it)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, bluetooth

I have this code from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1293303/300121), that start or stop to bluetooth service based on the argument it receives.

```
bluetooth.ps1 -BluetoothStatus On
```

or

```
bluetooth.ps1 -BluetoothStatus Off
```

I would like to modify it so that I can call it without argument with a simple ahk key binding:

```
#b::
Run, C:\Users\user\Desktop\bluetooth.ps1 
return
```

Then the script should "by itself" check if the bluetooth is on or off and do what is necessary to change the state : if on, it should stop it ; if off it should start it.

```
[CmdletBinding()] Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet('Off', 'On')][string]$BluetoothStatus
)
If ((Get-Service bthserv).Status -eq 'Stopped') { Start-Service bthserv }
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::RequestAccessAsync()) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
$radios = Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::GetRadiosAsync()) ([System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]])
$bluetooth = $radios | ? { $_.Kind -eq 'Bluetooth' }
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioState,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Await ($bluetooth.SetStateAsync($BluetoothStatus)) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic is in the last few lines of code:

```
$bluetooth = $radios | ? { $_.Kind -eq 'Bluetooth' }
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioState,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
Await ($bluetooth.SetStateAsync($BluetoothStatus)) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus])
```

The variable $bluetooth holds the current state of the bluetooth radio:

```
PS C:\> $bluetooth

     Kind Name      State
     ---- ----      -----
Bluetooth Bluetooth    On
```

So before that last line where we call Await again and pass in the parameter $BluetoothStatus, which set to either 'Off' or 'On', we can use a conditional to the value.

```
if ($bluetooth.state -eq 'On') {$BluetoothStatus = 'Off'} else {$BluetoothStatus = 'On'}
```

Now we can remove the parameter line:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet('Off', 'On')][string]$BluetoothStatus
```

And everytime we call the script it should reverse the current state.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailled answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best of both worlds.

- To toggle on/off call `powershell -Command bluetooth.ps1`
- To turn explicitly on call `powershell -Command bluetooth.ps1 -BluetoothStatus On`
- To turn explicitly off call `powershell -Command bluetooth.ps1 -BluetoothStatus Off`

```
[CmdletBinding()] Param (
    [Parameter()][ValidateSet('On', 'Off')][string]$BluetoothStatus
)
If ((Get-Service bthserv).Status -eq 'Stopped') { Start-Service bthserv }
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::RequestAccessAsync()) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
$radios = Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::GetRadiosAsync()) ([System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]])
$bluetooth = $radios | ? { $_.Kind -eq 'Bluetooth' }
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioState,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
if (!$BluetoothStatus) { if ($bluetooth.state -eq 'On') { $BluetoothStatus = 'Off' } else { $BluetoothStatus = 'On' } }
Await ($bluetooth.SetStateAsync($BluetoothStatus)) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
```