# Pairing the Bluetooth device through a KIOSK application for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bluetooth, file-transfer

I need to create a kiosk application in which I need to allow user to share files via Bluetooth. So, for that I have developed a GUI which will allow user to [turn on and off Bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/1494499/modify-a-powershell-that-receive-argument-on-off-to-start-stop-service-to-a-scri),list all available Bluetooth devices,show status of device (paired,connected etc.), pair the device. For each of these functions, I have explored [Bluetooth command line tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/) and [32 feet .NET library](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet). Both libraries seems to work for all except pairing the device. In Windows 10, pairing the device command when sent usually pops up the windows notification to pair when clicked redirects to the windows settings page. But in kiosk mode, I cannot allow windows notifications and settings to popup.

Alternately, I have tried to open the devices and printers page of the control panel from which user can add device and pair and this method works. But I cannot allow user to access other windows pages from the control panel.

So, I have tried to create an overlay which would allow user interaction in only selected areas of the panel while masking the rest of the regions (similar to tutorial mode in our mobile apps). I would also want to add a button for the user to press when he is done, so that I can close the overlay and the panel. But here i am facing the below issues,

1. Opening the control panel as a child window
   I tried to open the control.exe application inside C# windows Form, I am able to open Notepad but when i tried to open the control panel threw an "Process has exited, so the requested information is not available" exception.
2. Adding a button on the form
   I tried to create button(Close) in parent form but the button does not close the child and parent form but in turn crashes.
3. Disabling user interaction in masked areas.
   I am able to draw an overlay but the button under the overlay are still accessible especially the close button since it is always in the top right corner.

- OS - Windows 10
- Architecture - x64bit
- development languages - C#, Java.

Comment: You have to disable Authentication agent through registry. Or use Bluetooth Framework that already does it.

Comment: I took a look at this bluetooth framework tool and I can see that there is a development license that is required to purchase.. if we do purchase, can we do unlimited deployments or does it require deployment license too?

Comment: It's royaltee free. That means that once purchased you can developer any number of applications and sell your applications without any limitations. And of course you can deplaoy the Bluetooth Framework together with your application without any additional fees. The only things you can not do are: redistribute Bluetooth Framework source code or sell it separately.