# Using Powershell to turn on/off the bluetooth: script doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, bluetooth

I'm want to switch on/off Bluetooth using a shortcut. So I found this script [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1494499/modify-a-powershell-that-receive-argument-on-off-to-start-stop-service-to-a-scri).

But my problem is that it doesn't work for me. In fact, it seems to do nothing. I tried to run the script without parameters and with parameters, but each time nothing happened. BT stays in the same state.

Do I need to do something before trying this script? (Including a package or a library in the script? Activating something in Windows?)

For information, I'm using Windows 10 with the last update available.

NEW: I tried something: showing some results by removing some `| Out-Null`.
Then I have this message `DeniedByUser` when the script goes to the Await() function.

Here is the script:

```
[CmdletBinding()] Param ( [Parameter()][ValidateSet('On', 'Off')][string]$BluetoothStatus )

If ((Get-Service bthserv).Status -eq 'Stopped')
{
    Start-Service bthserv
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]

Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType)
{
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1)  | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}

[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::RequestAccessAsync()) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus])# | Out-Null
$radios = Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::GetRadiosAsync()) ([System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]])
$bluetooth = $radios | ? { $_.Kind -eq 'Bluetooth' }
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioState,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null

if (!$BluetoothStatus)
{
    if ($bluetooth.state -eq 'On')
    {
        $BluetoothStatus = 'Off'
    }
    else
    {
        $BluetoothStatus = 'On'
    }
}

Await ($bluetooth.SetStateAsync($BluetoothStatus)) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus])# | Out-Null
```

Information: the line `$netTask.Wait(-1)` shows a good result if I remove the `| Out-Null`.

Here is the result after running this script:

```
True
DeniedByUser
True
DeniedByUser
```

Any idea on where can be the problem?

Comment: Are you able to run any script at all?

Comment: Yes I can run another script without problem. I never used WinRT before, so do I need to do something to use it correctly?

Comment: See [if this helps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/switch-bluetooth-off-and-on-via-powershell/m-p/2403524/highlight/true#M2698)