# Replicate Windows Lock Bluetooth Discovery

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth

I recently bought at Razer Orochi v2 mouse because it supports both BT and RF. This allows me to switch between work and personal PC quickly. I have the same feature on my keyboard, so I only need one set of peripherals on my desk. The mouse uses BTLE tech.

**Issue**: When I switch from RF to BT, the mouse will sometimes just not reconnect to my laptop. All other bluetooth peripherals work fine, I've updated drivers, gone through troubleshooting etc... nothing has helped. It will happen about 50% of the time, and I'm stuck toggling it between modes for 2 minutes before getting it to reconnect.

**Resolution**: The only thing that seems to work 100% of the time is pressing WIN+L to lock my PC, and it magically connects the mouse... every damn time. Now I can't rely on this method because it is just a pain, when I switch between my personal and work PC 50-100 times a day.

**Question**: Is there a way to replicate whatever Windows 10 is doing when I use WIN+L to lock the PC, I assume it's kicking the BTLE chips/stack/software in some way to tell it to rediscover any devices. If I could script this, I could probably bind it to a keybind to at least manually force this to happen on my own. I've attempted to find data on what it's actually doing with no success.

Any info/assistance is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What happens if you click `Win+K`?

Comment: Also, for your setup you might want to take a look at [Logitech Flow](https://www.howtogeek.com/317962/how-to-use-logitech-flow-for-mice-and-keyboards-across-multiple-computers/), it could speed up your workflow A LOT

Answer (score 1):

You may do
[Turning Bluetooth on or off](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-bluetooth-on-or-off-in-windows-9e92fddd-4e12-e32b-9132-5e36bdb2f75a#Category=Windows_10)
to cause the re-discovery of your devices.

Useful commands ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/850650/how-can-i-toggle-bluetooth-on-and-off-via-a-shortcut-or-script-in-windows-8-1)) :

```
net start "bthserv"
net stop "bthserv"
```

The post
[How to connect and disconnect a Bluetooth device with a PowerShell script on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642702/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-a-bluetooth-device-with-a-powershell-script-on-win/53648715#53648715)
has this PowerShell script:

```
$device = Get-PnpDevice -class Bluetooth -friendlyname "FriendlyDeviceName"
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
```

See also the
[Bluetooth Command Line Tools](https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools)
for useful utilities.

Comment: The Bluetooth Command Line Tools are for classic BT rather than BLE. Not sure if the other commands apply to BT or BLE or both.

Comment: Testing will tell.