# Fast, less steps way (preferably single step from system stray icon) to enable disable bluetooth in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth, notification-area

Before I Win 8.1 in Win 7 I used to typically get a Bluetooth Icon in the System tray (courtesy of the MS or non MS driver stack).

**System Tray, the old way:**
It was quick, intuitive and straight access path way to enable/ disable bluetooth and access bluetooth settings, pair new devices and/ or reconnect with previously paired devices that at times (maybe because they are multi point paired with other devices as well) do not automatically reconnect.

**Hardware Switch / Fn + Function Key - Not available:**
Since, my current and new devices do not have a hardware or Fn + keyboard based quick enable/ disable of Bluetooth etc & WiFi etc. I'd like to find a Win 8.1 way that will work on most devices.

**Metro metro, Go away:**
I do not like Metro and its screens and have disabled it and use Classic Shell so I do not wish to do this via Metro.
http://www.surfaceforums.net/threads/add-the-bluetooth-device-pairing-shortcut-and-tile-you-really-need-windows-8-and-8-1.8420/

**All the ways, and none as straight forward:**
So, I found a bunch of these ways online while googling and I feel these are still round about and mis-directed ways which are less convenient and straight forward as the **System Tray icons** I had before.

I did find the Win+C (Charms) > Settings would have been "do able" but it only gives quick access to WiFi, bluetooth is a bunch of more steps inside Metro type PC Settings.

And of course, because there is a System Tray icon for WiFi/ LAN it is a quick simple way to access and switch between networks (Wired and Wireless).

Ideally, this is what I'd have liked for Bluetooth as well in Win 8.1. Straight access to BT like WiFi from System Tray. Just the way we do so in Mobile Device (iOS & Android) panels for quickly changing: Airplane, WiFi, Bluetooth, etc.

**Are there existing ways? Windows Hacks? Some software/ tiny app/ utility? Some Keyboard shortcut ways to do so?**

What I've already read and it's not fast/ quick enough with less steps as before:

- [How to turn on/off Bluetooth on Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/612742/how-to-turn-on-off-bluetooth-on-windows-8-1)
  This answer seems to be tempting/ promising but I dont see any of it.

  > **[Device Manager]**
  >   You will see the Bluetooth Radio Adapter is disabled,
  >   even the service is ON. Now right-click on it and enable the driver.
  >   When the icon appeares beside the clock, you are able to turn the
  >   Bluetooth on and off normally from Wireless setting.
- http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/42347-bluetooth-turn-off-windows-8-a.html
  **(Bluetooth ways)**
- http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/41506-wi-fi-turn-off-windows-8-a.html
  (**WiFi ways**; Bluetooth does not have the same kind of quick access, that it did before)
- http://www.groovypost.com/howto/turn-bluetooth-on-off-windows-81/

Comment: In Windows 10, click on Start, type 'blu' and Enter, this brings up 'Bluetooth Settings'. Something similar might help for Windows 8.1?

Comment: @gogoud - No dice :)